# Column reference is ambiguous for local variable in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

The following is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  add_config_to_enterprise(configKey character varying, enterpriseValue character varying) RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
entId character varying;
   BEGIN
        FOR entId IN
    SELECT enterprise_id
    FROM tenant
LOOP
    INSERT INTO enterprise_configuration(enterprise_configuration_id, product_configuration_id, enterprise_id, value)
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT uuid_generate_v4(),
        (SELECT pc.product_configuration_id
        FROM product_configuration pc
        WHERE pc.configuration_key = configKey), 
            entId, enterpriseValue) AS tmp
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT e.enterprise_configuration_id
            FROM enterprise_configuration e
            WHERE e.enterprise_id = entId AND e.product_configuration_id = 
                (SELECT p.product_configuration_id
                FROM product_configuration p
                WHERE p.configuration_key = configKey));

END LOOP;


   END;

$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

But its giving me following error when this function is called

```
ERROR:  column reference "entid" is ambiguous
LINE 12:             WHERE e.enterprise_id = entId AND e.product_conf...
                                             ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

There is no column named `entid` present in any table. Why is it giving such an error?

Comment: Seems like you should 1) Qualify columns (`tablename.columnname`), 2) Chose another variable name.

Comment: I tried using different variable names, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery alias in the `WHERE` condition:

```
...
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT uuid_generate_v4(),
        (SELECT pc.product_configuration_id
        FROM product_configuration pc
        WHERE pc.configuration_key = configKey), 
            entId, enterpriseValue) AS tmp
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT e.enterprise_configuration_id
            FROM enterprise_configuration e
            WHERE e.enterprise_id = tmp.entId AND e.product_configuration_id = -- here
                (SELECT p.product_configuration_id
                FROM product_configuration p
                WHERE p.configuration_key = configKey));
...
```

or rename `entId` in the `SELECT` list of the subquery:

```
...
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT uuid_generate_v4(),
        (SELECT pc.product_configuration_id
        FROM product_configuration pc
        WHERE pc.configuration_key = configKey), 
            entId as eId, enterpriseValue) AS tmp -- here
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT e.enterprise_configuration_id
            FROM enterprise_configuration e
            WHERE e.enterprise_id = entId AND e.product_configuration_id =
                (SELECT p.product_configuration_id
                FROM product_configuration p
                WHERE p.configuration_key = configKey));
...
```

Comment: I didnt get it. why tmp.entId? entId is declared variable it should be used as it is right? Its working though, but didnt understand the reason why doesnt it work as I posted

Comment: Because you use it in a subquery you have two `entId`. Actually, they are the same but parser cannot know this. You have an alternative, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the subquery with the alias `tmp` you define in your query has a column named `entid`, so the parser doesn't know if the reference to `entid` in the `WHERE` condition refers to that column or to the function variable.

True, they contain the same value, so it doesn't matter in reality, but there is still a syntactic ambiguity.

You'd have to qualify the `entid` in the `WHERE` condition either with the alias `tmp` or with the name of the function `add_config_to_enterprise` to resolve the ambiguity.

Your query is unnecessarily complicated and ill-indented, so much so that I cannot  understand and improve it. Simplifying it would get rid of the problem.